# How to get the two numbers after the decimal point as an integer

Tags: java, eclipse, integer, decimal

I have the number "`159.82`" and I need to get it to print just "`82`" 
What I have been trying is something along the lines of

```
double total = 159.82;
System.out.println(total - (int) total);
```

But that leaves me with 0.8199999999999 so clearly I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way: Turn it into an String, use indexOf to find the ".", use substring to print 82.

Answer (score 0):

Would this fit what you're looking for? It outputs the decimal value, rounded to two places, as a String.

```
double total = 159.82;
String decimalValue = String.format("%.2f", total).split("\\.")[1];
System.out.println(decimalValue);
```

(Prints "82")

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `replaceAll`, so you can replace everything until the dot :

```
double total = 159.82;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(total).replaceAll("^.*\\.", ""));// output = 82
```

This can work either with negative numbers for example :

```
double total = -159.82; // output = 82
```

---

Another solution if you want to get only 2 numbers then you can use :

```
double total = 159.82; // positive or negative
int result = Math.abs((int) (total * 100) % 100);
System.out.println(result); // output = 82
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to how [float/double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) works, the easiest solution could be to work with strings. This will return the decimals of any double input.

```
double input = 159.82;

String decimals = Double.toString(input);
decimals = decimals.substring(decimals.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

System.out.println(decimals);
// prints "82"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final int fraction = Integer.valueOf((total+"").replaceFirst("-?\\d+\\.", ""));    
System.out.println( fraction );
```